# CKEditor issue with drag and drop image upload

Tags: php, upload, ckeditor

I'm having some difficulties configuring uploadimage plugin on CKeditor to permit drag and drop of images.

I included both plugins uploadimage and it's dependent uploadwidget.

This is the upload php file:

```
$basePath = "/var/www/html/images/articles/";
$baseUrl = "/var/www/html/images/articles/";

$funcNum = $_REQUEST['CKEditorFuncNum'] ;

    if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {

        $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $basePath . $name);

        $url = $baseUrl . $name ;

       $message = 'new file uploaded';   
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'No file has been sent';
    }


    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message')</script>";
```

The problem is with CKEditorFuncNum, since I'm not receiving anything from the form.

File is correctly uploaded into the $basePath but the function window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction fail due to the missing funcNum

```
ckeditor.js:3 [CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error. 
Object {responseText: "<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: CKEditorFu…icles/371c63d.jpg', 'new file uploaded')</script>"}
```

Do you guys know why I'm not getting anything from $_REQUEST['CKEditorFuncNum'] ?

THanks

Comment: As error say looks like you don't have index CKEditorFuncNum, try to check your request with  `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Yes it's right! i do not receive the CKeditorFuncNum index but I do not understand why it's not coming from the editor

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked docs on [File Browser API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) describing creation of custom file manager?

As for **CKEditorFuncNum**, I would check if it is a problem with CKEditor or PHP code. Just check the upload request in the browser dev console to see if CKEditor adds **CKEditorFuncNum** param:
[image]

And then depending on the cause you may try to dive deeper.

Comment: Intersting point! I just figured out that I didn't include the filebrowser plugin :-/ 
I'm doing it right now and let you now if it was the problem.

Comment: CKEditorFuncNum is not present in the list of parameters sent within the form. any other suggestion?

Comment: `<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: CKEditorFuncNum in <b>/var/www/html/newPadmin/libs/upload.php</b> on line <b>43</b>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(, 'images/articles/Appartamento_vendita_Torino_foto_print_609700762.jpg', 'new file uploaded')`

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console or any CKEditor files which are not loaded properly? I assume you configured http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserUploadUrl and http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl properly. Have you checked if it is not a cache issue after enabling filebrowser plugin?